# Identifying a field on Crystal Report XI

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a formula field titled "Truck Miles" whose formula is

```
Endingodo - Startingodo
```

But I cannot seem to find where the value for Ending or Starting odo come from.
It is not a field within the table nor is it a value within Formula field.

Where could it be coming from? [image]

Answer (score 2):

StartingOdo and EndingOdo are custom variables that have been initiated in another formula. Line 2 and 3 indicate these are NumberVar (Number Variables), but they are not being created here, they are just being called for evaluation (Ending - Starting)

I am not aware of any function within Crystal to find these - I would personally just check each formula on the report to find them.

Comment: is this where it is being created?, WhilePrintingRecords;
Numbervar StartingOdo;
Numbervar EndingOdo;
Numbervar OOBillCount;
Numbervar OOBillMiles;
Numbervar COBillCount;
Numbervar COBillMiles;
if StartingOdo = 0 and {VW_RPT_NUT_TRUCK.ODO_READING} > 0 then
StartingOdo := {VW_RPT_NUT_TRUCK.ODO_READING};
if EndingOdo = 0 and {VW_RPT_NUT_TRUCK.ODO_READING} > 0 then
EndingOdo := {VW_RPT_NUT_TRUCK.ODO_READING};
if StartingOdo > 0 and EndingOdo > 0 then
if Endingodo < {VW_RPT_NUT_TRUCK.ODO_READING} then
EndingOdo := {VW_RPT_NUT_TRUCK.ODO_READING};

Comment: Looks like it. StartingOdo is being set to {VW_RPT_NUT_TRUCK.ODO_READING} (if ODO_READING is > 0) and EndingODO is also being set to {VW_RPT_NUT_TRUCK.ODO_READING}. VW_RPT_NUT_TRUCK is a view from your data source. Does that help?

Comment: Sure does, but how does it know which values within that column, considering there are over 220 records for the time period ?

Comment: Where is the formula that you just posted located in the report? There is usually a 'reset' formula used to set the variable's value to 0. Depending on where the reset formula is placed, it will affect which value is being assigned to the variable... Hard to explain, but if there are 5 records for each truck, ordered by date, they could print the STARTINGODO at the group header and print the ENDINGODO at the group footer. Without seeing the report, it's tough to tell for sure. What is the reason you are looking at these values? is there a problem with the calculation?

Comment: The values for Starting ODO and ending ODO appear to be calculating the MIN and MAX values, whereas I want to calculate the values based off of the timestamp so the StartingODO should be the very first ODO value and the Ending ODO would be the very last value. Yes there are two reset formulas and no this was pulled from another report...

Comment: I can't answer definitively what the best way to handle that is. Depending on your report structure, you could group and sort according to timestamp, use variables, etc. I would suggest starting with a blank report and only look at the timestamp and ODO readings - figure out what works for you and then implement that in your actual report

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115140/discussion-between-ovo-and-aron).